# "What are you up to?"

Tags: idiom

I would like a Latin phrase to ask what the other person is doing at the moment.
For example, it would not be unusual for me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm) to first say "hi" and then ask what the other person is doing.
I don't know what would be idiomatic.

There is the simple option *quid facis?*, but I would assume there are other options as well.
I don't want to have all my conversations in the exact same words.
A Finnish idiom ("mitäs puuhailet?") could be translated directly as *quidnam factitas?*, but I suspect there are better options.

How would you ask such a question in Latin?
Why so?
I am looking for something for modern use, but it can be from any era.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John Milton's short poem of 1639, 'Epitaphium Damonis', has *Heus bone numquid agis? nisi te quid forte retardat, Imus?'*

Milton is a reliable and excellent authority for examples of Latin syntax. This one ought to suggest one or two variations for you to consider.